# Proof of differentiability of $f$ at $z_{0}$ implies that $f'(z_{0})=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$, $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $z_{0}\in \Omega^{\circ}$. Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $z_{0}$ then $f'(z_{0})=0$.

---

My sketch:

We know that $f$ is differentiable at $z_{0}$, so $f$ is continuous at $z_{0}$. In particular
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}} f(z)-f(z_{0})=0
\end{align}
Then if
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_{0}} \frac{f(z)-f(z_{0})}{(z-z_{0})}(z-z_{0})&=0\\
f'(z_{0})(z-z_{0})&=0
\end{align}
which means $f'(z_{0})=0$ or $z-z_{0}=0$. By hypothesis $z_{0}\in\Omega^{\circ}$, there exists $r>0$ such that for $h\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|h|<r$, $z_{0}+h\in B_{r}(0)\subset \Omega$, which means $|z_{0}+h|<r$. In particular for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<r$ we have $|z-z_{0}|<r$, so $z-z_{0}=0$ isn't possible and $f'(z_{0})=0$. Is this correct?

Comment: You cannot just take the limit of the difference quotient but not of the factor $(z-z_0)$. It should read $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to z_0 } \frac{{f(z) - f(z_0 )}}{{z - z_0 }}(z - z_0 ) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to z_0 } \frac{{f(z) - f(z_0 )}}{{z - z_0 }}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to z_0 } (z - z_0 ) = f'(z_0 ) \cdot 0 = 0.
$$Also, what is $\Omega^\circ$?

Comment: $\Omega^{\circ}$ is the interior of $\Omega$

Comment: Take $\Omega$ to be the unit disc, $f(z)=z$, $z_0$ any point inside the unit circle. Then $f'(z_0)=1\neq 0$. The statement you are trying to prove is completely false in general. In fact, it holds only for constant functions.

Comment: As mentioned, this isn't true. Can you tell us what has lead to you trying to prove it?

Comment: Thank you @Gary

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC It's a statement from exercise list from the topic of complex derivate

Comment: but I don't know if this case there exist other condition to come true is statement

Comment: It couldn’t be that $f$ maps to $\Bbb R$ instead?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Yes, Cause doesn't work with $\mathbb{C}$